# Binding the data

Tags: silverlight

how to bind the data in datagrid in silverlight appiliaction project.with out using the List concept.

Comment: list more easier than others.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean binding the grid but not using List? I'm not sure what is your limitation of using List , but you can use IEnumerable or ObservableCollection where T is the class that you bind the grid rows to. (Un?)forunately, Silverlight has no DataSets so if you come from WinForm world, you now have to use objects for data binding, same as you would have used BindingList in WinForms or Object DataSource in ASP.NET.